# glTexImage2D acces violation

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, textures

Ive already posted this question, but it did not get any usefull answers. I'm trying to create two textures in OpenGL. Initially i did it like this:

```
unsigned int texture1, texture2;
glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
int width, height, nrChannels;
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\wall.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
```

This code works perfectly fine and runs with no visible issues. Obviously building these textures are the exact same procces both times, and so i figured I would use a for loop instead:

```
unsigned int textures[2];
int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\wall.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
glGenTextures(2, textures);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        stbi_image_free(data);
        data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (i == 0) ? textures[0] : textures[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, (i = 0) ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But this code breaks completely with the error: Unhandled exception at 0x03C78893 (ig9icd32.dll) in LearnOpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0A47B000.

I am sure you can point out lots of things that you dont like about the code, or stuff that maybe could become a problem later on, but seeing as i really just want an answer for this specific problem, please dont post an answer unless you have something that will actually make this code compile.

Comment: @Swordfish This is not duplicate, because the  `(i = 0)` issue is in this question, but not in the other one.

Comment: @Rabbid76 you are right in that regard. But since the code over there is basically the same short of the flaw you pointed out in your answer the two questions are at status quo again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(i = 0)` is an assignment in

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, (i = 0) ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

This causes that the control variable `i` of the `for` loop, is continuously set to 0 and the loop never terminates.

You have to use the compare operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`:

```
(i == 0) ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA
```

---

Note, the expression

```
(i = 0) ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA
```

is evaluated as

```
0 ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA
```

which results in

```
GL_RGBA
```

The first image is an image with 3 color channels, but because of the wrong operator you try to read 4 color channels and access the `data` buffer out of bounds. This causes the access violation when reading the data:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0A47B000.